# ember.js using the same controller and view for different routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I wanted to make a searchQuery that needs to go to the server and fetch new data (the query has to be in the server Filter is not an option)

So I figured out that I must have a different route for search

(using ember_cli)
I have a hbs/controller/route named `sessions`
And now I added a route `search-sessions.js`
The search function in the `sessions` controller calls: `this.transitionToRoute("search-sessions", query);`

I wanted to not DRY so I tried to make `search-sessions.js` work with `sessions` controller/hbs (they are exactly the same other than the fact that they have a query passed to the server)

I tried adding the following code in `search-sessions.js` route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      return this.store.findQuery('session', params.filters);
    },
    controllerName: 'sessions',

    renderTemplate: function() {
      this.render('sessions');
    }
  });
```

The thing is - that the model/view doesn't get updated unless I refresh the page

If I duplicate the code (separate hbs/controller for `search-sessions` it will work but will miss the point of not duplicating code)

Comment: Take a look at [mixins](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) ([cli-version](http://www.ember-cli.com/#mixins))

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to refresh the model:

```
App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return ['pink', 'orange', 'green'];
  },
  controllerName: 'common',

  renderTemplate: function() {
   this.render('common');
  }
});
```

What are you doing different? Can you reproduce your issue in the following jsbin?

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yukaxe/2/edit

Comment: well... I'm using transitionToRoute because the search is by a button, not seeing any other major differences...

Comment: I updated the jsbin to transitionTo() (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yukaxe/3/) the model is still refreshing...

Comment: well... thanks for the help... Silly me - I have a filteredElements property I have in sessions controller. I needed to have it observe model.[]